# CppUnit Libraries Full of Undefined References?

Tags: c++, linux, reference, undefined, cppunit

I'm trying to use CppUnit but have noticed that anytime I get to the linking phase of my code I'm being told I have a bunch of undefined references from things like CppUnit::TextTestRunner etc. I confirmed these were undefined by looking at libcppunit.a and sure enough most of the .o files are nothing but undefined references. I tried rebuilding and making the installation but noticed that if finishes during make with /link being unable to find references to said interfaces. Has anyone else experienced this on a SUSE 10 linux distro? Any ideas how to get those libraries linked in? We are running on SGI Altix Itaniums if that is of anyhelp.

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Are you mixing C and C++ code? It may be the C++ [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is causing this